# react-scroll desde una vista diferente

Tags: reactjs, scroll

quiero realizar una navegación hacia la vista main y después que se realice un scroll automático al element o el id (yo lo tengo con un element). Ahora mismo funciona el scroll pulsando Relatos Cortos siempre y cuando esté en la vista de Main, pero si cambio, el link ya no me envía al id o element.

He comprobado hacerlo con la etiqueta  y me navega pero sin el scroll, exclusivamente al id y de una manera super brusca, nada que ver con el react-router-dom.

¿Quizás haya que hacerlo de manera manual con javaScript y no utilizando react-scroll?

He leído que debería navegar a los id que tenga detro de mi DOM, sin embargo no lo hace, si me podéis indicar donde está el error o si hay que añadir algo más, os lo agradecería. Un saludo.

```
**COMPONENTE NAVBAR**

    import React from 'react'
    import './Navbar.css'
    import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
    import { Link } from 'react-scroll';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import HamburgerIcon from './imgNavbar/HamburgerIcon.png'
    
    const Navbar = () => {
    
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
        
        const toggleMenu = () => {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        };
    
        return (
            <div className='navBar'>
                <button  className='navbar-button'>
                    <img onClick={toggleMenu} src={HamburgerIcon} alt='icon hamburguer' />
                </button>
                <nav className={`navbar-nav ${isOpen ? "isActive" : ""}`}>
                    <NavLink to="/about"><p>¿Quién soy?</p></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/published"><p>Libros publicados</p></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/writing"><p>Escribiendo</p></NavLink>
                    <Link className="navBar-link"
                        activeClass="active"
                        to="stories"
                        spy={true}
                        smooth={true}
                        offset={-300}
                        duration={500}><p>Relatos cortos</p></Link>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Navbar

**COMPONENTE MAIN**

    import React from 'react'
    import CardBook from '../Card/CardBook/CardBook'
    import dataBook from '../Data/DataBooks.json'
    import dataStories from '../Data/DataStories.json'
    import './Main.css'
    import CardStories from '../Card/CardStories/CardStories'
    import { Element, Link } from 'react-scroll';
    
    
    
    
    const Main = () => {
    
    
    
    
      return (
        <div className='main'>
    
          <div className='titles'>
            <div className='titles-lineBar'></div>
            <h2>Libros</h2>
            <div className='titles-lineBar'></div>
          </div>
    
          <div className='booksContainer'>
            {dataBook.map((index) => (
    
              <CardBook
                key={index.id}
                title={index.title}
                synopsis={index.synopsis}
                paragraph={index.paragraph}
                image={index.image}
                buy={index.buy} />))}
          </div>
    
          <div className='titles'>
            <div className='titles-lineBar'></div>
            <

h2>Relatos cortos</h2>
        <div className='titles-lineBar'></div>
      </div>

      
        <Element name='stories' className='storiesContainer'>
          {dataStories.map((index) => (
            <CardStories
              key={index.id}
              title={index.title}
              synopsis={index.synopsis}
              paragraph={index.paragraph}
              image={index.image}
              url={index.url}
            />))}
        </Element>
      
    </div>
  )
}

    export default Main
```

Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: la siguiente respuesta deberia de ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588820/8705724